# Where is the create method for Eloquent Model?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Every model can be created in Laravel by [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#mass-assignment):

```
$flight = App\Flight::create(['name' => 'Flight 10']);
```

Where can one find the code of this method in Laravel 5.6?

I looked in the class `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` but I could not find a `create` method.

I also checked all the traits (from `HasAttributes` to `GuardsAttributes`) but I didn't find a `create`method there either.

[image]

Since the class `model` does not extend any other classes I am a bit puzzled where the `create` method is hidden.

Comment: you mean this? https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_create

Comment: What was your question exactly?

Because the accepted answer doesn't answer your question.

Comment: @NeelBhanushali, there is no create method on the Model class which is why I explained how it passes through to the Builder class.  This should answer the question.

Comment: @Devon 
my bad, i thought he needed the file location.

You have explained it well while everyone else has given the location.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eloquent Model uses magic methods (__call, __callStatic) to pass calls through to the Eloquent Builder class.  Therefore, Model::create() is actually passing the call to the Builder::create() method.

However, if you investigate that method, it is basically the same as calling:

```
$model = new Model($attributes);
$model->save();
```

This mixin of the (Query) Builder via passthrough is what allows you to use query methods like `Model::where()`

Answer (score 2):

You can find it in github [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php)

```
public function create(array $attributes = [])
{
    return tap($this->newModelInstance($attributes), function ($instance) {
        $instance->save();
    });
}
/**
 * Save a new model and return the instance. Allow mass-assignment.
 *
 * @param  array  $attributes
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|$this
 */
public function forceCreate(array $attributes)
{
    return $this->model->unguarded(function () use ($attributes) {
        return $this->newModelInstance()->create($attributes);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check following file

`PATH_TO_PROJECT/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php`